# Attribute Number of Rows

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, performance, eav, dropdown-attribute

I have a question about the number of Rows for one Attribute Code.
I have 3 Store View, can I create an Attribute with 500 Rows with different option for each Store View? Or this will create problems (performance etc).
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can have different labels for different views.

Comment: I know, I want to know if is too big and may cause problems have an Attribute with 500 rows with 3 different Labels (one for each View plus Admin Label)

Comment: Haven't had any problems with it so far. I guess you're good to go as well ..

Comment: Ok, thanks. I ask because now I have this attribute with 300 Rows and when I click on "Save" it take about 100 second to Save the change.

Comment: Ah .. I filled those attributes with import.

Comment: How you filled the attributes with import?

Comment: I wrote an extension that imports products from provider inventory system to Magento inventory. Among other things I also imported attributes and their values/labels.

Comment: Oh cool. Good idea but too late for me. :( I write about 400 attributes manually. I don't know if I can post it here but I need an help for another problem with attributes. I post my problem here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25678/images-related-to-attribute-label-in-view-phtml  Can you help with this problem? Thanks for your help.